# JohnTheRipper export session to different computer

Tags: john-the-ripper

I have had JohnTheRipper running for a few days (I do not want to lose this progress) and I would like to pause it, move all required files to a different computer and continue from where I stopped on that new computer.

John can pause a session which was created with `john --session=foo hashes.txt` simply by pressing Ctrl+C and resume it with `john --restore=foo`.
This obviously only works on a single computer.

How do I copy a session from one computer to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same version of john the ripper installed on both machines, you can copy the session files after hitting ctrl-c. You need `foo.rec` and `foo.log` (for session `foo`), which are usually in the directory you executed john from. Put them in the directory you'll be executing from on the new machine.

Double check the versions first though, or you might get an `Incorrect crash recovery file format: foo.rec` error.

Comment: Don't feel forgotten ;) I have read your answer but I have yet to try it. Somebody unplugged the computer, causing it to shut down (it's a laptop) and now it won't boot properly. I just didn't get around to recovering the files yet.

Comment: @NikoO No problem. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Yes! Found the files, copied them over, had to change the path specified in the .rec file because the files were in different locations, executed `john --restore=foo` and now it's continuing from where it left off.
Thank you very much.